# Swap errors in logs with encrypted home, 17.10 Artful Aardvark

Tags: 17.10, swap, cryptswap

I get this error 1 to 4 times per hour:

```
Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
Unit systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service has failed.
systemd-cryptse
crypt_init() failed: Block device required
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Maybe the swap file is in home and cannot be decrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of software updates later, this problem has disappeared :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar errors while starting up Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop, and I noticed that the swapfile wasn't being used. It turns out the installer made an incorrect entry for the encrypted swapfile in the `/etc/crypttab` file.

```
cryptswap1 /target/swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

The `/target` part is the path at which the Ubuntu installer mounts the target filesystem where installation will be done, and should only be used when booting from the installer media. Somehow this got left over on the installed configuration. I removed that part and rebooted, and now I don't see the cryptography error, and the swapfile is being mounted and used.

This is what my `/etc/crypttab` looks like now:

```
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, btw reboot is not needed. You can just do `sudo cryptdisks_stop cryptswap1` and `sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1`.

Comment: But I am getting `Failed to activate swap /swapfile.` after actually rebooting. So probably it's not the full solution.